# How to fetch one - one row from table

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, cursors, database-cursor

I have a table called `stud_ans_sheet`.

I want to run a loop
which would every time fetch next values from table.

It's a PL/SQL program and I am doing it with a cursor.
This is my program,
but it has a lot of errors:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
    cursor c_stud is select stud_no,ans from stud_ans_sheet;
    v_stud c_stud%rowtype;
    v_no stud_ans_sheet.stud_no%type;
    answer varchar(10);
    i number(3);
    v_corr stud_ans_sheet.corr_ans%type;
    v_wrong stud_ans_sheet.wrong_ans%type;
    v_unattempt stud_ans_sheet.unattempt_ans%type;
    score number(5,2);
    v_ans varchar(10);
    str1 varchar(40);
    str2 varchar(40);
    nval stud_ans_sheet.stud_no%type;
    total number(5,2);
begin
    answer:='AACCABAABD';
    open c_stud;
    loop
        fetch c_stud into v_stud;
        exit when c_stud%notfound;  

        for i in 1..10
        loop

            nval:= select seq.nextval from stud_ans_sheet.stud_no;
            select stud_no,ans into v_no,v_ans from stud_ans_sheet where stud_no=nval;
            str2:=substr(v_ans,i,1);
            str1:=substr(answer,i,1);

            if(str2=str1) then
                update stud_ans_sheet
                set corr_ans=v_corr+1;  
            elsif(str2='E') then
                update stud_ans_sheet
                set unattempt_ans=v_unattempt+1;
            else    
                update stud_ans_sheet
                set wrong_ans=v_wrong+1;        
            end if;

        end loop;           
        update stud_ans_sheet
        set score=corr_ans-wrong_ans*0.25+unattempt_ans;            
    end loop;
    close c_stud;
end;
/
```

Comment: Can you give some sample data - input and output of your expectation. Your question is not completely clear.

Comment: I edited the above statement

Comment: I have to make a Mcq test ... In which E is for unattempted. I have inserted 10 values in table. After the execution of the trigger i have to find the correct ans,wrong ans , unattempted answer and last have to find the score of all the 10 students

Comment: I have tried with single student and that i performing well but my need is to update all the fields in 1 trigger itself

Comment: do you get any Errors or what is the issue?

Comment: Yes... It's showing more multiple values are fetched

Comment: @JaicyJoseph: that isn't really an error message. I think you are probably getting a *PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:* at the line containing `nval:= select seq.nextval from stud_ans_sheet.stud_no;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed some of your code, try this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
   ANSWER        VARCHAR (10);
   V_CORR        STUD_ANS_SHEET.CORR_ANS%TYPE;
   V_WRONG       STUD_ANS_SHEET.WRONG_ANS%TYPE;
   V_UNATTEMPT   STUD_ANS_SHEET.UNATTEMPT_ANS%TYPE;
   STR1          VARCHAR (40);
   STR2          VARCHAR (40);
BEGIN
   ANSWER := 'AACCABAABD';

   FOR R_STUD IN (SELECT STUD_NO, ANS
                  FROM STUD_ANS_SHEET)
   LOOP
      V_CORR := 0;--It's better to have only one update
      V_WRONG := 0;
      V_UNATTEMPT := 0;

      FOR I IN 1 .. 10
      LOOP
         STR2 := SUBSTR (R_STUD.ANS, I, 1);
         STR1 := SUBSTR (ANSWER, I, 1);

         IF (STR2 = STR1)
         THEN
            V_CORR := V_CORR + 1;
         ELSIF (STR2 = 'E')
         THEN
            V_UNATTEMPT := V_UNATTEMPT + 1;
         ELSE
            V_WRONG := V_WRONG + 1;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;

      UPDATE STUD_ANS_SHEET
      SET SCORE = V_CORR- V_WRONG* 0.25 + V_UNATTEMPT,
          CORR_ANS = V_CORR,
          WRONG_ANS = V_WRONG,
          UNATTEMPT_ANS = V_UNATTEMPT
      WHERE R_STUD.STUD_NO = STUD_NO;
   END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: Thank u so much... Same i did today and it run successfully

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't really make sense:

```
nval:= select seq.nextval from stud_ans_sheet.stud_no;
```

There is no `variable := select ...` construction in PL/SQL, and even if there was, `stud_ans_sheet.stud_no` isn't a table so you can't `select` from it, and if you could it's unclear what you want the sequence for anyway.

If you just want to copy the record attribute `v_stud.stud_no` into the local variable `nval` then you can just use:

```
nval := v_stud.stud_no;
```

but then the question is why copy it at all, when you can just use `v_stud.stud_no` directly?

It is generally best to avoid the verbose declare-open-fetch construction for cursors when all you need to do is loop through them. Instead, you can just use:

```
for r in (
    select stud_no, ans from stud_ans_sheet
)
loop
```

I can't see why you are re-querying `stud_ans_sheet` in the loop just to get back the same row you already have. If it's something to do with your `update` logic, I couldn't tell what that was supposed to do.

The `update` statements in your code will update every row in the table every time, because they don't have any `where` clause.

In PL/SQL, `if` conditions are terminated by `then` instead of being enclosed in brackets as in some other languages, so for example,

```
if (str2 = str1) then
```

can be decluttered into:

```
if str2 = str1 then
```

The construction `for i in 1..10` implicitly declares `i` with its scope as the loop, so the other `i` you declared at the top is a different variable and not used.

You are allowed to use spaces for readability, so

```
update stud_ans_sheet
set score=corr_ans-wrong_ans*0.25+unattempt_ans
where ...
```

can be written more clearly as

```
update stud_ans_sheet
set    score = corr_ans - wrong_ans * 0.25 + unattempt_ans
where  ...;
```

Probably you should focus on one error at a time rather than dumping the whole thing here for review.

Comment: Ok i will try that. thank you for taking your precious time for answering.

Comment: There are 10 rows in my table. And i want to update all the rows one by one. How to fetch one row ?

Comment: *How to fetch one row?* The cursor loop is already fetching one row at a time. If you mean *how to update one row*, then add a [`where` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5).

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

    DECLARE
       aswer varchar (10);
       v_corr number(3);
       v_wrong number (3);
       v_unattempt number (3);
       str1  VARCHAR (10);
       str2 VARCHAR (10);
    BEGIN
       answer:= 'AACCABAABD';

       FOR v_stud in c_stud
       LOOP
          v_corr:= 0;
          v_wrong:= 0;
          v_unattempt := 0;

          FOR I IN 1 .. 10
          LOOP
             str2 := SUBSTR (v_stud.ans, i, 1);
             str1 := SUBSTR (answer, i, 1);

             IF (str2 = str1)
             THEN
                v_corr := v_corr + 1;
             ELSIF (str2 = 'E')
             THEN
                v_unattempt := v_unattempt + 1;
             else
                v_wrong:= v_wrong + 1;
             END IF;
          END LOOP;

          UPDATE stud_ans_sheet
          SET 
              corr_ans= v_corr,
              wrong_ans = v_wrong,
             unattempt_ans=v_unattempt , score = v_corr- v_wrong* 0.25,
          WHERE stud_no= v_stud.stud_no;
       END LOOP;

    END;
    /
```